# How to type a particular kind of unit vector?

Tags: vector

I write unit vectors frequently. Right now, the best thing going for me is to define:

```
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
```

and then do

`\uvec{i}`, `\uvec{j}`, and `\uvec{k}`. I like the results (they're clear enough), but I would prefer no dots for the `i` and `j` unit vectors. What's a nice, unified way to get that?

I tried `\hat{\textbf{\i}}`, and that works ok, as does `\hat{\textbf{k}}`. The problem is that `\hat{\textbf{\j}}` doesn't work for me. For some reason, I don't get a `j`, but some rectangular blob of ink.

`\jmath` and `\imath` don't work for me, because I don't want italics but bold-face.

So, to sum up:

1. Want bold, not italic
2. Want a hat over the unit vector
3. Want no dot for the `i` or `j` unit vectors.

How best to get all this? Thanks very much for your time!

Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$\uvec{i}, \uvec{j}, \uvec{k}$
\end{document}
```

Please feel free to suggest the inclusion of other packages.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `$\hat{\textbf{\j}}$` gives the desired result, so probably it is a problem with fonts in your installation. Your  *.log file may help to find the reason.

Comment: Yes, I just found out that including the times package causes the blobs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use `\i` and `\j`, which means you need to switch to text mode. However, there is a problem that text fonts in math mode inherit the attributes of the context, so, for example, `$\textbf{\i}$` would give a bold italic dotless i in a theorem statement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\uveci}{{\bm{\hat{\textnormal{\bfseries\i}}}}}
\newcommand{\uvecj}{{\bm{\hat{\textnormal{\bfseries\j}}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\uvec}[1]{{%
  \ifcsname uvec#1\endcsname
     \csname uvec#1\endcsname
   \else
    \bm{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}%
   \fi
}}

\begin{document}
$\uveci\ne\hat{\imath}_{\uvec{i}}+\uvec{j}+\uvec{k}$
\end{document}
```

You can type both `\uveci` and `\uvec{i}` for uniformity, the same for a “j”.

[image]

You can't use the `times` package for this; first of all because it's obsolete, but even its substitute, that is `mathptmx`, doesn't provide a dotless j. You can use `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\uveci}{{\bm{\hat{\textnormal{\bfseries\i}}}}}
\newcommand{\uvecj}{{\bm{\hat{\textnormal{\bfseries\j}}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\uvec}[1]{{%
  \ifcsname uvec#1\endcsname
     \csname uvec#1\endcsname
   \else
    \bm{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}%
   \fi
}}

\begin{document}
Some text for showing that Times is being used.

$\uveci\ne\hat{\imath}_{\uvec{i}}+\uvec{j}+\uvec{k}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With newTX you also have the possibility of getting upright lowercase Greek letters. Here's how to do it; I also added the possibility of typing `\uvec{\alpha}`. Please, be aware of the fact that the argument of `\uvec` must be a *single* Latin character (not `\i` or `\j`, which are unnecessary and illegal for the macro) or a *single* Greek symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\uveci}{{\bm{\hat{\textnormal{\bfseries\i}}}}}
\newcommand{\uvecj}{{\bm{\hat{\textnormal{\bfseries\j}}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\uvec}[1]{{%
  \ifcat\relax\noexpand#1%
    % it should be a Greek letter
    \bm{\hat{#1}}%
  \else
    \ifcsname uvec#1\endcsname
      \csname uvec#1\endcsname
    \else
      \bm{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}%
     \fi
   \fi
}}

% for upright lowercase Greek; newtxmath hasn't an option for this
  \let\alpha\alphaup
  \let\beta\betaup
  \let\gamma\gammaup
  \let\delta\deltaup
  \let\epsilon\epsilonup
  \let\zeta\zetaup
  \let\eta\etaup
  \let\theta\thetaup
  \let\iota\iotaup
  \let\kappa\kappaup
  \let\lambda\lambdaup
  \let\mu\muup
  \let\nu\nuup
  \let\xi\xiup
  \let\pi\piup
  \let\rho\rhoup
  \let\sigma\sigmaup
  \let\tau\tauup
  \let\upsilon\upsilonup
  \let\phi\phiup
  \let\chi\chiup
  \let\psi\psiup
  \let\omega\omegaup
  \let\varepsilon\varepsilonup
  \let\vartheta\varthetaup
  \let\varpi\varpiup
  \let\varrho\varrhoup
  \let\varsigma\varsigmaup
  \let\varphi\varphiup
%%

\begin{document}
Some text for showing that Times is being used.

$\uveci\ne\hat{\imath}_{\uvec{i}}+\uvec{j}+\uvec{k}$

$\uvec{\alpha}+\uvec{\Gamma}+A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Note

The Times font is by no means necessary and the code works as well with the standard fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\uveci}{{\bm{\hat{\textnormal{\bfseries\i}}}}}
\newcommand{\uvecj}{{\bm{\hat{\textnormal{\bfseries\j}}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\uvec}[1]{{%
  \ifcat\relax\noexpand#1%
    % it should be a Greek letter
    \bm{\hat{#1}}%
  \else
    \ifcsname uvec#1\endcsname
      \csname uvec#1\endcsname
    \else
      \bm{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}%
     \fi
   \fi
}}

\begin{document}

$\uveci\ne\hat{\imath}_{\uvec{i}}+\uvec{j}+\uvec{k}$

$\uvec{\xi}+\uvec{\Gamma}+A$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think my solution is to not include the times package. Then my command works fine with `\i` and `\j`.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I added a way to have Times and the dotless j.

Comment: Excellent! I like that a tad better than without. The text is just a bit darker and easier to see.

Comment: Hmm. Your `NewRobustCommand` isn't compiling for me. I'm getting a `! Missing \endcsname inserted.` error message.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I just did a copy-paste from the file I produced the image with.

Comment: Hmm. It compiles if I use your code as a MWE. But when I embed it into my larger document, it doesn't work. Let my try the package game again...

Comment: @AdrianKeister Are you perhaps trying something like `\uvec{\alpha}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15635/discussion-between-adrian-keister-and-egreg).

Comment: Ah, man: those Greek unit vectors are beautiful. Thanks a bundle, man!

Comment: There is something a little bit off with the dotless j; may I suggest a `\skew` of `{.5}`?

Comment: @morbusg I can't see the need of it.

Comment: Well as I said, the difference is really subtle, but still noticeable. Here's a picture with the one with skew on left, and one without on right: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/VS0BL53.png)

Comment: @morbusg Blame the author of `bm`. ;-)

Comment: Actually my above picture was made with Plain `:-)`

Comment: I have tried @egreg's suggestion and I have a display issue with letter "j". Any help, please? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb9aK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb9aK.png)

Comment: @Miculas13 You probably have `\usepackage{mathptmx}`. Replace with `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$\uvec{\i} \uvec{\j} \uvec{k}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! The `bm` package fixed the problem nicely. I'll start including that now.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`? However, try this in a theorem statement.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't solve my problem. I'm still getting the blob. Let me see if I can figure out if there's a package problem...

Comment: Ok, if I also include the times package, I get the blob.

Comment: @AdrianKeister There are many good reasons not to use the `times` package, not least of which is the ugliness of Times.  There's a question here somewhere on this site...  But I'm guessing the `\j` glyph is not defined for that font package.

Comment: Right-ho. I just tested the results without the `times` package, and found that I liked it well enough. The `bm` package didn't seem to make any difference, if I've already included the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes, I am reasonably sure that `amsmath` just loads the `bm` package, though I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{bm}


\begin{document}

$\bm{\vec{a_{1}}}$ = a $\bm{\hat{\imath}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is italic, not bold like I requested.

Answer (score -1):

You can use your command but `\uvec{\i}` and `\uvec{\j}`. This will produce what you want.