# Can't make unit vectors with greek letters

Tags: macros

I have this command

```
\let\oldhat\hat
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

for making bold vectors. And have this commands here

```
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ihat}{\hat{\textbf{\i}}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\hat{\textbf{\j}}}
\newcommand{\khat}{\hat{\textbf{k}}}
```

for making unit vectors from an letters (wich works) and the traditional i,j,k unit vectors.

The problem is that I can't make unit vectors from greek letters with `\uvec{}`. I can do it with

```
\hat{\vec{\xi}}
```

for example, but not with the more comfortable `\uvec{}`.

How can I do this?

Comment: For Greek letters you need math mode. In math mode \textbf doesn't work. It should be replaced with \mathbf.

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188775/how-to-type-a-particular-kind-of-unit-vector ? The Times font is not really a requirement, there. Just remove the calls to `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` and the `\let` instructions for the upright Greek.