# How can have a unit vector symbol without bold?

Tags: symbols, bold, vector, bm

This is the following question from [How to type a particular kind of unit vector?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188775/how-to-type-a-particular-kind-of-unit-vector)

This given have bold, but I just want ordinary without bold. How can I do that?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$\uvec{\i} \uvec{\j} \uvec{k}$
\end{document}
```

I had tried:

```
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{#1}}}
```

not working.

Comment: `$\hat{n}$` it is without **bold** using `amsmath` package.

Comment: *You* are requesting boldface with those definitions. Just do `\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\hat{#1}}` However, you need `\uvec{\imath}` and `\uvec{\jmath}` to remove the tittle.

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Do you want the hats not be bold but the text be bold?